# Footer page number from Word document

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-c++, vba, ms-office

I'm having a problem in MS Word interop. I'm using VC++, but I'll accept suggestions in C# as well.

In a word document having a page number given in the footer when I use the SaveAs method I am getting a random page number instead of the correct can any one can help me.

I've also tried using PageNumbers.GetStartNumber and Range.GetInformation methods with no luck.

How to get the actual page number which is in footer from Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I was able to solve it using this code. in VC++

```
Selection oSelection = m_oApp.GetSelection();
Sections ss = oSelection.GetSections();
Section s = ss.GetFirst();
HeadersFooters hf = s.GetHeaders();
HeaderFooter hfItem = hf.Item(1);
PageNumbers ps = hfItem.GetPageNumbers();

//to get the First pageNumber

long nNo = ps.GetStartingNumber();
HeadersFooters footers = s.GetFooters();
HeaderFooter footer = footers.Item(1);
Range r = footer.GetRange();

//to get the First page footer text
CString strFooterText = r.GetText();
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't C# or VC++, but the VBA version would like this. The page number is probably a field, so use the Selection if you have one.

```
Public Sub GetPageNumber()
    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler

    Dim currentDocument As Document
    Set currentDocument = ActiveDocument

    Debug.Print Selection.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text 'Or...
    Debug.Print Selection.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields(1).Result

    Exit Sub

MyErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "GetPageNumber" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Err = " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```